# Open .bat from python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` in a folder with an `exe` named `abcexport.exe` with the following code inside :

```
abcexport.exe myswf.swf
```

Double-clicking the bat as normally on windows exports the `swf` as expected.

I need to do this from within python, but it complains abcexport is “not recognized as an internal or external command”.

My code :

Attempt 1 -

```
os.startfile("path\\decompiler.bat")
```

Attempt 2 -

```
subprocess.call([path\\decompiler.bat"])
```

Also tried the same with `os.system()`, and with `subprocess` method `Popen`, and passing the argument `shell=True` ends up in the same

Comment: Using `shell=True` is unnecessary for running a .bat with `Popen` (and `call`, etc). The underlying `CreateProcess` call knows to run the shell that's set in the `ComSpec` environment variable.

Comment: Since the batch file relies on the working directory, you need to set it using the `cwd` parameter. That said, the .bat is badly written. It should reference its directory as `%~dp0`, i.e. the [d]rive and [p]ath of the script (arg 0).

Comment: When you run the batch file by double-clicking, it works because Explorer sets the working directory to the directory of the batch file.

Comment: @eryksun My fault, that exactly works like a charm. Thanks a lot  !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Use the relative or absolute path to batch.bat as well, unless it's on the search `PATH` or in the working directory of the current process.

Answer (score 0):

A .bat file is not executable. You must use cmd.exe (interpretor) to "run it". Try

```
import subprocess
executable="path\\decompiler.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", executable, 'myswf.swf'], shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

in order of the .bat to work

Comment: `WindowsError: [Error 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado` -> Can't find the file.. 

same replacing `\\` with `\\\`, `/`, `//`, with `r"C:\Windows\System32..."`, and with bot `os` and `subprocess` methods...

Comment: I'v updated my answer with a more precise example.

Comment: Also, make sure abcdexport.exe is in the PATH, or use dirname (abcdexport.exe) as working directory (for popen args)